# How do I send an Httprequest answer to a container using IdentityModel

Tags: c#, odata, identityserver3

I have this code that is working perfectly:

```
    public string CallApi2(TokenResponse response)
    {
        String resp = "";
        var client = new HttpClient();
        client.SetBearerToken(response.AccessToken);
        resp=client.GetStringAsync("http://localhost:50158/test").Result;
        return resp;
    }
```

Now I need to put in this one working to fill the container:

```
var container = new Default.DataGolfeContext(new Uri(serviceUri));
```

That should be something like this, but it dons't work:

```
var container = client.GetStringAsync( new Default.DataGolfeContext(new Uri(serviceUri)));
```

Can somebody help me on this?

Comment: Are you attempting to send a payload, namely the data in the `DataGolfeContext`, in the `GET` request?  You can't do that, `GET` requests cannot contain payloads.

Comment: Are you looking for POST ?

Comment: This is an API consuming app and it is working for the code above when the anser is a normal jason. But i had other services that answer odata, and dose are the one called inDatagolfeContext with a specific URI

Comment: Your code is wrong. `HttpClient.GetStringAsync` takes a string or URI as its argument, and returns a `Task<String>` result.